# Why does Java's concat() method not do anything?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

This code:

```
String s = "TEST";
String s2 = s.trim();

s.concat("ING");
System.out.println("S = "+s);
System.out.println("S2 = "+s2);
```

results in this output:

```
S = TEST
S2 = TEST
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Why are "TEST" and "ING" not concatenated together?

Comment: Link to documentation: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: The same reason `trim()` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

a String is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), meaning you cannot change a String in Java. [concat()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) returns a new, concatenated, string.

```
String s = "TEST";
String s2 = s.trim();
String s3 = s.concat("ING");

System.out.println("S = "+s);
System.out.println("S2 = "+s2);
System.out.println("S3 = "+s3);
```

Answer (score 10):

Because `String` is immutable - class `String` does not contain methods that change the content of the `String` object itself. The `concat()` method returns a new `String` that contains the result of the operation. Instead of this:

```
s.concat("ING");
```

Try this:

```
s = s.concat("ING");
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is:

```
s2 = s.concat("ING");
```

The concat function does not change the string s, it just returns s with the argument appended.

Answer (score 3):

`concat` returns a string, so you are basically calling concat without storing what it returns.
Try this:

```
String s = "Hello";
String str = s.concat(" World");
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(str);
```

Should print:

```
Hello
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

`.concat()` method returns new concatenated value. 
there you did `s.concat("ING")`--> this gives return value "Testing". But you have to receive it in declared variable.

If you did `s=s.concat("ING");` then the value of "s" will change into "TESTING"

Answer (score 0):

As String  is immutable when concat() is called on any String obj as

String  s ="abc";
new String obj is created in String pool ref by s

s = s.concat("def");
here one more String obj with val abcdef is created and referenced by s