# String concat in java

Tags: java

I am trying to concat String array values in a String, The below code does not work

```
private void newString() {

    String str = "Split me"; 
    String[] tokens = str.split("[ ]+");

    String newStr = new String();

    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
        newStr.concat(tokens[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("NEW STRING IS : " + newStr);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Main m = new Main();
    m.newString();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [why concat() is not working here? , java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818796/why-concat-is-not-working-here-java)

Comment: Try changing the regular expression in your split() from `[ ]+` with `\\s+` to follow the [patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) predefined by the Javadocs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String` is immutable. Naturally, [`String.concat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) returns a brand new `String`.

> ... a new `String` object is created, representing a character sequence that is the concatenation of the character sequence represented by this `String` object and the character sequence represented by the argument string.

The way you're trying to do it, the code should look like...

```
String glued = "";

for (final String token : tokens) {
  glued = glued.concat(token);
}
```

Now, the problem I have with this approach is that you're doing a *lot* of copies of the `String` data. Each `concat` copies all of the data in `glued` as well as the data in `token`. Now, think about the implications of that... I'm not a fan of premature optimization, but I believe the logical way to achieve this is to instead use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) as follows...

```
final StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for (final String token : tokens) {
  buf.append(token);
}
final String glued = buf.toString();
```

Answer (score 10):

When you call `newStr.concat(tokens[i]);` this *doesn't* modify `newStr`, it returns a new `String` that is the result of the concatenation. You aren't doing anything with the result.

You need to do something like: `newStr = newStr.concat(tokens[i]);`

`String` is an immutable type in java, so it's methods work like this, returning a new `String` object. Consider using a (mutable) [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead. `StringBuilder` maintains an internal buffer that can grow, and so avoids the unnecessary `String` copies that come with using concatenation and immutable `Strings`.

Comment: Interesting, pb2q... we posted at the exact same time.

Answer (score 2):

I try to fix it with StringBuilder,here is the new codes.

```
private void newString() {
    String str = "Split me"; 
    String[] tokens = str.split("[ ]+");
    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
        newStr.append(tokens[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("NEW STRING IS : " + newStr);
}
```