# Android:String concatenation in Toast doesn't work

Tags: java, android, toast, string-concatenation

I've designed an app, part of which requires me to display a toast based on how many input fields are left empty.
Here's my code snippet-

```
if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))||(isEmpty(Age))||(isEmpty(phoneNumber)))
{
    String text="Following fields are empty:";
    if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))){
        text.concat("\nName");
    }
    if ((isEmpty(Age))){
        text.concat("\nAge");
    }
    if ((isEmpty(phoneNumber))){
        text.concat("\nPhone Number");
    }
    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

Here `isEmpty()` returns True if the input field is empty, else it returns false.
Now, I expected the output (when all fields are empty), to show

`Following fields are empty:
 Name
 Age
 Phone Number`

However, it only shows `Following fields are empty:` .

Where's my mistake?

RESOLVED- Instead of concat(), I used `text+="name"` and so on.
But why didn't concat() work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the newline characters. Are you sure that Toasts support multiline by nature?

Comment: no, it was an issue of using concat(). See my updated question

Comment: Android is basically using Java. I'm a tad out of touch, but would expect you need to use text = text.concat("\nName");

Comment: Ohhhhh... that's because of String immutability. At each call of "concat", a new String is created. Sorry, I didn't notice the error previously.

Comment: Check my answer for a bit more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `text.concat("\nName");`

to

```
text = text.concat("\nName");
```

And same for `age` and `Phone Number`

i.e. simply use

```
if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))||(isEmpty(Age))||(isEmpty(phoneNumber)))
{
    String text="Following fields are empty:";
            if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))){
                text = text.concat("\nName");
            }
            if ((isEmpty(Age))){
                text = text.concat("\nAge");
            }
            if ((isEmpty(phoneNumber))){
                text = text.concat("\nPhone Number");
            }
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Or Simply use as

```
if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))||(isEmpty(Age))||(isEmpty(phoneNumber)))
    {
        String text="Following fields are empty:";
                if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))){
                    text +="\nName";
                }
                if ((isEmpty(Age))){
                    text +="\nAge";
                }
                if ((isEmpty(phoneNumber))){
                    text +="\nPhone Number";
                }
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
```

Comment: Yup, that's what was causing the trouble. Thank you.

Comment: @Deathstroke,Happy to help,Accept as answer,if it helped.

Comment: I was going to. It says I need to wait 8 minutes. Don't worry.I'll accept it.

Comment: @Deathstroke Thanks,You may use my edited answer also.Anyway Enjoy coding.

Comment: @Deathstroke See why concat not working in your case at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818796/why-does-javas-concat-method-not-do-anything

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))||(isEmpty(Age))||(isEmpty(phoneNumber)))
{
    String text="Following fields are empty:";
            if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))){
                text = text.concat("\nName");
            }
            if ((isEmpty(Age))){
                text = text.concat("\nAge");
            }
            if ((isEmpty(phoneNumber))){
                text = text.concat("\nPhone Number");
            }
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

change `text.concat("\nName");` to `text = text.concat("\nName");`

Like:

```
if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))||(isEmpty(Age))||(isEmpty(phoneNumber)))
{
    String text="Following fields are empty:";
            if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))){
                text = text.concat("\nName");
            }
            if ((isEmpty(Age))){
                text = text.concat("\nAge");
            }
            if ((isEmpty(phoneNumber))){
                text = text.concat("\nPhone Number");
            }
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After each call to concat(), a new String is created, because Strings in Java are 'immutable'. As in, a new object instance is allocated, so it's better to use a StringBuffer for concatenation of multiple strings.

Therefore, the proper way of doing this would be the following:

```
if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))||(isEmpty(Age))||(isEmpty(phoneNumber)))
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("Following fields are empty:");
            if ((isEmpty(firstName))||(isEmpty(lastName))){
                sb.append("\nName");
            }
            if ((isEmpty(Age))){
                sb.append("\nAge");
            }
            if ((isEmpty(phoneNumber))){
                sb.append("\nPhone Number");
            }
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
}
```

Also, the reason why

```
string += "hello";
```

works, is because that translates to

```
string = string + "hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this: `text += "\nName";`

Comment: Yes, this is what I used