# How to concatenate string in java

Tags: java, string, printing

Here is my code for string concatenation.
StringSecret.java

```
public class StringSecret {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String("abc");
        s.concat("def");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I expected that the output will be "abcdef" but I am getting only "abc" printed. What's the problem !.

Comment: possible dupliacte http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818796/why-does-javas-concat-method-not-do-anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, string **objects are immutable**. Immutable simply means unmodifiable or unchangeable.
Once string object is created its data or state can't be changed but a new string object is created.

**so to get the output as "abcdef"  write "s.concat("def");"**

**Example**

```
public class StringSecret {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = new String("abc");

    s = s.concat("def");
    System.out.println(s);

  }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

In java strings are immutable. It cannot be changed. `concat(...)` function doesn't change the value of `s` but it just return the concated value passed as argument with `s`.
You will have to store it in another variable or print it directly or use `s = s.concat("def")`

```
String c = s.concat("def");
System.out.println(c);
```

For the note, you can just use `c = s + "def";` in java or `s += "def"`

Comment: Why is it necessary to store it into another variable? Can you please clarify!

Comment: @faizalvasaya `String` is immutable, that is why.

Comment: I have just started studying "Strings" in Java , because of the same I am not aware about the term "Immutable". Can you please elaborate on it.

Comment: Immutable means it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = new String("abc");
s.concat("def");
```

[image]

```
 String s = new String("abc");
 s = s.concat("def");
```

[image]

Note:- Don't initialize string like this `String a = new String("abc");`
just use this `String a = "abc";`

Comment: I appreciate your efforts for clarifying my doubt. It helped me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String s = "Strings are immutable";
      s = s.concat(" all the time");
      System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings dont mutate so the result of the concatenation must be assigned to something otherwise will be lost
example:

```
String s = new String("abc");
s = s.concat("def");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s.concat("def");
 System.out.println(s);
```

You are concatenating correctly, but you are not saving the result of concatenation anywhere.